# React Native - populating ListView with async data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting a list of `items` as a `prop` through the redux store. This prop is asyncronous.

My ListView works with syncronous hardcoded data. So the problem is populating with the prop when I actually receive it.

I'm making a ListView out of this item prop data. What's the best practice on life cycle choices to setState with this prop? I've tried `componentDidMount` - but that's too early and only called once. I tried `componentWillReceiveProps` - I get the prop, but my view doesn't change. I also tried `componentWillUpdate` and I get too many calls! I'm tempted to put it in the render function because I know I can grab that prop when I get it but that makes the render function no longer pure.

Thanks for any help!

```js
this.setState({
  dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.props.items);
})
```

Comment: If you have the answer to your problem, can you please write an answer to your own question and accept it? It looks like you did so in your update, but doing so in an answer as well will be clearer that this question is solved.

Comment: for some reason I'm not allowed to accept it, but its written

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was that I actually needed to convert items as a `List` from immutable to a JS `Array` for the ListView. Not what I originally thought the problem was in the question.

Here's the solution:

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    if(newProps.items){
      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newProps.items.toJS())
      })
    }
  }
```

I'm still wondering if I'm using best practice by using `componentWillReceiveProps`. I'm also wondering if it's a little strange that I have to convert from a List to an Array, but if it's purely presentational that is ok, right?

Answer (score 0):

When using `componentsWillReceiveProps`, it's good practice to check whether those props have changed. Also not sure why you have to do `.toJS()`, you just need to return a new array so React knows to update.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
  if (newProps.reasonOptions !== this.props.reasonOptions){
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows([...newProps.items])
    });
  }
}
```